# Making include directories relative to root folder instead of project location using premake 5?

Tags: premake

I'm using the latest premake 5 alpha to generate Visual Studio projects and my project structure looks something like this:

```
root
----include
--------Core
------------Window
----------------Window.h
----src
--------Core
------------Window
----------------Window.cpp
----project
--------Core
------------Core.vcxproj
--------Engine.sln
----premake5.lua
```

Premake script:

```
solution "Engine"
configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
includedirs { 
    "external/include",
    "include"
    }

filter "configurations:Debug"
    defines { "DEBUG" }
    flags { "Symbols" }
    targetname "%{prj.name}_D"

filter "configurations:Release"
    defines { "NDEBUG" }
    optimize "on"
    targetname "%{prj.name}_R"

project "Engine-Core"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C++"
    files {
        "include/Core/**.h",
        "src/Core/**.h",
        "src/Core/**.cpp"
    }
    includedirs {
        "include/Core/"
    }
    targetdir "lib"
    location "project/Core"
```

I've setup my premake script so that the project files will be generated in the project folder in my root directory using the location function. I've used the includedirs function to add the include folder in my root folder. I've specified it to be relative to the premake script. When I look at the include directories in my project in Visual Studio the directories are relative to the folder where the project is generated. In this case it would be "....\include". What ends up happening is that the Window.h file cannot be found if I try to include it in the Window.cpp file.

I can get everything to work if I generate the solution and projects files directly in the root folder. I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Is there a way to modify my script so that I can keep my source code organized in a nested folder structure while generating my project files in a separate folder for Visual Studio?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to see the relevant portions of your Premake project script.

Comment: I have added the script.

Comment: Your only include dir is `"include/Core/"` so if you `#include "Windows.h"` it won't find it. You should either add `"include/Core/Windows"` to the include dirs or `#include "Windows/Windows.h"` And if it's just a typo, and you *are* indeed doing things correctly, then it's definitely a bug. I'm using almost the same folder hierarchy on my projects, and it works fine :)

Comment: What about the include dirs under the solution? "external/include" and "include"? Are they not applied to every project in the solution?

Comment: I don't know, but they are still not pointing to `"include/Core/Windows"` so even if they are correctly added to the project's include directory (which you can verify by simply opening your solution/project and checking the include directories), writting `#include "Windows.h"` still wont work because the directory where `Windows.h` is located is not added as an include directory.

Comment: Yup, that's it. You should write that as an answer though so it can be accepted and up-voted! And yes, directories specified at the solution level should be applied to all projects.